# agregar texto al principio de mi fichero de texto

Tags: python

estaba intentando agregar texto a un fichero de texto al principio pero siempre me lo pone al final.
Mi pregunta es como podria hacer para que el texto que agrego , en python me lo agregue al principio y no al final? Tendre un fichero de texto cualquiera ej:

```
Mifichero.txt
```

Entonces queria ponerle texto al principio tal que.

> El nuexo texto que escribire en  mi fichero

Alguna manera posible de poner el texto al principio usando python?

Answer (score 2):

Depende de como se esta abriendo el archivo según [`a,w,a+,r..`](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/lectura-y-escritura-de-archivos/) para escribir antes puede usar la opción `r+` en una función así:

```
def primeralinea(archivo, nuevotexto):
    with open(archivo, 'r+') as f:
        contenido = f.read()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.write(nuevotexto.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + contenido)

primeralinea('Mifichero.txt','textonuevo')
```

Comment: Esta forma es la mejor y la más sencilla

Comment: no me funciono intente poniendolo y no lo hace?

Comment: acabo de mirarlo y se me fue un espacio llamando la función y daba un error de iindentacion. puede probar nuevamente.